# Keep X most recent entries for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `elos` that looks like this:

```
id    username    elo    created_at
-----------------------------------
1     user A      152    date
2     user A      200    date
3     user B      100    date
4     user C      30     date
5     user A      79     date
...
```

I would like to keep the 30 most recent entries for each user, the rest should be deleted. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: It's often quicker to create a new table, retaining only those rows you wish to keep, and then replacing the old table with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods.  One is:

```
delete e
    from elos e join
         (select e2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by user_name order by created_at desc) as seqnum
          from elos e2
         ) e2
         on e.id = e2.id
    where e2.seqnum > 30;
```